# Passing values between SWFs

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I can reach child SWF's var from parent SWF but I would like to pass parent var to child to inform and operate different things in child (depends on var, basic if condition). Is it possible to load SWF and pass a var or value with it?

---

```
private function callFile()
{
    loader = new Loader;
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
    loader.load(new URLRequest("main.swf"));
}

private function onLoaded(e:Event)
{
    level_no = loader.content['level'];
}
```

---

This is parent->child variable read. And I want it two-way transfer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To pass a parameter between a "parent" swf to its loaded "child" swf, you can use a [`LoaderContext`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/LoaderContext.html) object to do that like this :

**loader.swf (parent) :**

```
var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
    context.parameters = {'passed_param': 'value'};

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.load(new URLRequest('loaded.swf'), context);
    addChild(loader);
```

**loaded.swf (child) :**

```
trace(this.loaderInfo.parameters.passed_param); // gives : value
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: I am away from the file so I cannot test it but I will take your help asap. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the child SWF instead of `loader.content['level'];` use `loaderInfo.loader.loaderInfo.content['myVar'];`. myVar is an variable defined in the parent SWF.

Comment: Little confusion here.
-Does this mean that method also works child to parent?
-or is using 'loaderInfo.loader.loaderInfo.content' better?

Comment: Use `loaderInfo.loader.loaderInfo.content` to pass variable from child to parent.
Use `loader.content['level'];` to pass variable from parent to child.

You can't use `loader.content['level'];` to pass variable from child to parent because you don't have `loader` in the child.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. It is great to hear the basic logic works both ways. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Any public defined method or variable in the swf can be called or accessed. If you define a method named doSomething in your swf then you can do:

```
MovieClip(loader.content).doSomething(myParentVariable);
//or
var level:int = MovieClip(loader.content).level;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the query parameter to load your swf :

loader.load(new URLRequest("main.swf?var=17&var2=lol"));

Then, in your child swf, use :

```
stage.root.loaderInfo.parameters.var
stage.root.loaderInfo.parameters.var2
```

It will do the job.

Comment: It throws unhandled IOError (#2044) and URL not found (#2035). The path is correct but...